# eclipse c++ SDL_Image library not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl-2

This is my code.

```
#ifndef LOADBMP_H_
#define LOADBMP_H_

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "res_path.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"
SDL_Texture* loadTexture(const std::string &file, SDL_Renderer *ren) 
{
    SDL_Texture *texture = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, file.c_str()); <-- troublesome line
    if (texture == NULL)
    {
        logSDLError(std::cout, "LoadTexture");
    }
    return texture;
}

#endif /* LOADBMP_H_ */
```

When I try to compile, it gives me an error: undefined reference to `IMG_LoadTexture'
I have properly installed the library. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have correctly installed it, it looks like you haven't linked it properly. You need to link the library in the same way that you would for SDL2 and SDL2_main.

For example in the image below you would add SDL2_image to it (this is Windows but same applies for other platforms on Eclipse)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I had linked SDL_image instead of SDL2_image.